# Using a custom TTF in Android makes for really ugly text

Tags: android, fonts

I have an app that contains a custom view, and in it I want to use a custom font. Unfortunately, this results in really ugly text being rendered.

My custom view extends Surface (and just realized: is this a bad idea), and I draw the text with the following code:

```
// p = new Paint();
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(parent.getAssets(), "komtit.ttf");
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
p.setTypeface(font);
c.drawText(this.text, x + width / 2 - p.measureText(this.text) / 2, y + height / 2, p);
```

The result looks like this:

http://img.skitch.com/20101014-rxw8j8igj1jci2fx9ui32ejcp.jpg

Not fun. I'm using p.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) but even with that the result is just fudgly.

So, is there a way to improve custom TTF rendering, or should I just stick to the system fonts?

Comment: the Droid fonts are high quality and made for on-screen rendering; so it may actually be the case that you are using font that isn't hinted properly for low-res displays. The font may look good when printed or in larger sizes but still look really crappy on a display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here. The problem was that I was extending Surface (which I really in the end didn't have a proper reason for) which apparently uses OpenGL for rendering and OpenGL and custom TTF fonts don't mix.

When I switched to extending just View, the font looks perfect.