# How do we type in Telugu in android? Is it supported?

Tags: android

Can we have Telugu typing in android? If so, how?
Does android support Telugu fonts directly?
Or do we use bitmap fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.sriandroid.telugu).

Indic version of Samsung phone supports most Indian language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom font to include telgu font, see the following guide to add support for custom font in your application:

[Add custom font for complete android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926263/add-custom-font-for-complete-android-application)

Comment: yes, [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3932951/1089811)

Answer (score 0):

One can easily type in Telugu using [multiling](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.klye.ime.latin&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rbHllLmltZS5sYXRpbiJd) app and its [Telugu plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=klye.plugin.te&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImtseWUucGx1Z2luLnRlIl0.).
It works in almost all applications. Prior to Jelly bean, Android did not support Telugu fonts.
But now, they do support it.