# Make My Own font for android

Tags: android, android-fonts

Hi I want to make my own font for arabic text in android. I've googled and I found tools like font struct and others. the question is I think that those tools will make me generate ttf font that is not specific for android and it might not look good on android devices I'm I right????. I feel confused :(

Answer (score 1):

As Android support [TrueType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) fonts, there shouldn't be any problems what so ever with any TTF you might put in your app.

The main problems that might occur is that if your font as small details, the rendering software will remove them on low resolution screens, or simply replace them with Droid (see [this](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/)) when the renderer fails completely.

Comment: I've read this post and replacing them is what I meam by "it might not look good"..but thank u

Comment: To be franc I've never seen this behavior while using custom font for standard Unicode characters and edited the post to add it.
 
Every thing should go fine just try !
if you have "ugly" rendering you can look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932951/using-a-custom-ttf-in-android-makes-for-really-ugly-text)  : the font renderer is not the same depending on the Widget type : in general it seem to use [Skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/) that perform fairly on all vectorial shape (including TrueType letters) but as you can read in the given link that might change ...

Comment: But be aware that you can have surprises with spacing and word-linking (i don't know if this is a pain in arabic)

Comment: mmmmm...ok I tried lots of fonts for arabic the system simply replaced them with sans that is what I'm afraid of...and I can't change the widget...But I'll read about skia...thanks alot